# Json data extract using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, google-places-api

I have json format like this -

How can i get the photo reference value? I have tried a lot.

```
{
"debug_info" : [],
"html_attributions" : [
   "Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.yellowpages.com.au/\"\u003eYellow Pages\u003c/a\u003e"
],
    "results" : [
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.859618,
           "lng" : 151.208017
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png",
     "id" : "4eb1c6eb8ec71a621f4d88e9aef77b0fce7ac304",
     "name" : "Harbour Rocks Hotel Sydney",
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 196,
           "html_attributions" : [],
           "photo_reference" : "CoQBeAAAAKTzIvsp1PJml8nzzxCAggrnyEu1-J3B6YbWhf3SMJLadZODgKnkEvWuXwKemOM4xc0IQpBv3LmkPOOZvXEuM0PBNp6YfvQc1EOHR_UF9K87ITUfM4f1nCnTFWpWjXFY5J4Aw1z1hJdu0LGfqcszeaImXBRxdzxlUw0Z9QTK-wWOEhCrs6v7gxJVLymtHl0WGv33GhTq_DgXtofepJ909JqOFrXw90fOEQ",
           "width" : 294
        }
     ],
     "rating" : 3.7,
     "reference" : "CoQBeAAAAHzr_LYm87OynYHffSsOFLsqzQO3iWo_DrC-JE8oZUNvYwyAlzumN0F9S87Lb2AbZrejbpbzvGC0JEy1-R52WbME4sRfqOYpM1AAvTRXVjMLus6ZRjU0nnJOGxyJdEdPRcPURThiTMDqH2AB9p4cGyqLtdKdG8hSNTcVOBykIAt7EhD6quPd7PCrVy4aETt8lYarGhRWuRNfSsnzsEdJ2MecTUXV0F65uQ",
     "types" : [ "cafe", "bar", "lodging", "food", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "34 Harrington Street, The Rocks"
  },
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.87054,
           "lng" : 151.198815
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png",
     "id" : "c71365287e7606bd21a3311d21fda087830b7813",
     "name" : "Pancakes on the Rocks",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : false
     },
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 1224,
           "html_attributions" : [
              "\u003ca href=\"https://plus.google.com/105663944571530352563\"\u003eJoshua Gilmore\u003c/a\u003e"
           ],
           "photo_reference" : "CnRoAAAAj1WWQDr0Uh-Naj8Fzg413dzP-3mix2O53r9mZEvRUaMEWZGiHthrE-whJhuW-aIUhyL-yk47DXOXR1DKHD5UacOzi99xTjSCNLXN-5_xetw_9xyRZkLofzamziEFoijl2v_JPthE46BoZRl6fQmeaBIQewa4UNPWTksaCfBBgckw-hoUBFtYJ87HMq2ZrCGPRhW0euefWYc",
           "width" : 1632
        }
     ],
     "price_level" : 2,
     "rating" : 3.8,
     "reference" : "CoQBcgAAAAcnHQk8ynZuToE6HAMJIRklS06ldx7XJXv5AhKQgIgXLURw71KoI_u3bAZ6Fv5X_LUv0QdTX_hQIwZpdLtegQvHOyIFKSRjeKw7_G-cdC7Ly_mJAzB-fXHhJlgKmHTFZ8J-WdK5ZjU7mm9ABBG0Q4rvoN5vyAWGfYGYX3JpKDmgEhA-s27w07KdpRZ7wLoaQKhZGhQdXJoNOqN1wuu0RC_f3c--EjUnGg",
     "types" : [ "cafe", "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "Harbourside Shopping Centre,Darling Harbour,227/229-230 Darling Drive, Sydney"
  },
.
.
.

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: This should work as I have become succesful to get value of latitude , longitude ,vicinity .**$.each( data.results, function( key, value ) {
   alert(value.photos[0].photo_reference);
}**

Comment: That should work, are there any errors in your javascript console? What is the alert showing?

Comment: the scrpit is not working at all. nothing alerted and if comment this alert then the code is alright :(

Comment: Did you check your javascript console? I bet there's an error there.

Comment: yeah there is an error and this is **TypeError: e is undefined
http:,../jquery-1.9.1.min.js
Line 3**

Answer (score 2):

The photo reference is in an array so you will need to loop over the "results" array, and then loop over the photos array (assuming that there could be more than one) and then you would have access to the "photo reference".

```
var data = { JSON HERE }
$.each(data.results,function() {
 $.each(this.photos,function() {
    console.log(this.photo_reference);
 });
})
```

Comment: there is an error and this is TypeError: e is undefined http:,../jquery-1.9.1.min.js Line 3

Comment: The JSON is missing a closing array bracket ], I corrected this, and then I ran this in Firebug and was able to access all the photo references

Comment: then what can i do plz?

Comment: The above code works. Just set "data" equal to your JSON object and then it should log the photo_reference to your firebug console. If you include your script that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Say that this JSON object is in a javascript variable called `placesJSON` you can access the first map result like this:

`placesJSON.results[0].photos[0].photo_reference`

To get each of the photo_reference in all results, you should loop over the results like this:

```
for(var placeIndex in placesJSON.results){
  for(var photoIndex in placesJSON.results[placeIndex].photos) {
    var reference = placesJSON.results[placeIndex].photos[photoIndex].photo_reference;
    // Do something with the reference here
    console.log(reference);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if your json is valid, then try following (pre-condition: photo_reference is not an array)

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator (
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($yourJsonString,TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

$result = array();
$i = 0;

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if ($key == 'photo_reference')
        $result[$i++] = $val;
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use in our api's with json.. i just use jquery to parse the json.  From there treat it like an object   var whatIneed = Obj.Variable

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonList.length; i++) {
    var photojson = $.parseJSON(jsonList[i]);
    var photo = new Object();
    photo.title = event.title;
    photo.id = event.id;
    ...
    photolist.push(ev);
}
```

and this should work, with some tweaking of course